# Javascript, listener and tagName

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why it's don't work.
I start in JS...
sorry for my bad english.

`var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('td');`

```
function redirect(i) {
    document.location.href='link?xx='+elm[i]+';
}

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  elm[i].addEventListener('click', redirect, false);
}
```

`

Comment: Replace 25 with `elm.length`. Also the function wont receive `i` since you do not pass it, just use `this` in it for the element.

Comment: and  fix your function call addEventListener('click',  redirect(elm[i))

Comment: @Stefan Avramovic: That will call it instead of binding it. Either bind it or just use `this` in `redirect` instead of `elm[i]`.

Comment: can you try `elm[i].addEventListener('click', redirect(i), false)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a fue syntax errors in your code.
You can create a callback function and call a redirect inside it

```js
var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
function redirect(e) {
  //document.location.href='link?xx='+e.innerHTML; 
  console.log(e.innerHTML)
}
for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
  elm[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){  
    redirect(e.target)  
  }); 
}
```

```html
<table id="outside">
  <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I must place the scripts before or after the table ?

Comment: You need to insert the script after table

Comment: Or wrap the code with window.onload = function() {

};

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Pleas consider marking the answer as a correct answer :)